# What does cstdint stand for?

Tags: c++

I know the [purpose of cstdint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) as a header to provide more accurate descriptions for numbers, but what does the actual header name stand for?

I have a hard time remembering shortened names, especially in programming, when I don't know what the full name is. I imagine it's something like "c standard type defintions integers" or something, but I can't quite find the explanation of the name.

What is the etymology of cstdint?

Comment: 'stdint' part seems self explanatory, are you interested in the 'c' prefix?

Comment: it's obvious once you're used to the naming conventions in c, but I'm still relatively new to the c/c++ world, at least outside of microcontroller world where I don't use the standard library much/at all. If you don't know the naming conventions or their history it's not as obvious as it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"C standard library integer support header" is a reasonable description.

- The `c` prefix indicates that it's a carryover from C, where it is called `<stdint.h>`. It's standard practice for C headers named `<foo.h>` to be named `<cfoo>` in C++.
- The `std` part is because it's part of the C standard library, and parallels other C library headers like `<stdio.h>` ("standard I/O") and `<stdlib.h>` ("standard library" -- an admittedly super generic name for what amounts to a grab bag of general purpose functionality that didn't fit into other headers).
- As you've guessed, the `int` part is because it provides a bunch of integer types and constants.

Comment: I like to use C standard width integer library but nice answer, +1

Comment: @NathanOliver the header also defines aliases that aren't related to a fixed width, like `intptr_t`.

Comment: Ah this is super helpful. I think c/c++ naming still trips me up b/c of the lack of camel or kebab case in the names to delimit each part. I kept thinking it was c-s-t-d-int instead of c-std-int :facepalm:. Once you pointed that out it was like seeing one of those magic eye paintings :P Thanks for explaining it :)

Answer (score 2):

`<cstdint>` has code from the C header `stdint.h`. C++ has a convention where C headers have the same base name, except for a leading c and no trailing .h

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to explain it. I didn't realize there was a previous `stdint.h` header. It makes a lot more sense now.